# Improve display of booking and rooms

Tags: calendar, booking

On campus we have some large electronic boards (see the image below) displaying 6 rooms. Each color represents a seperate room, and shows when that room is booked.

[image: https://scontent-arn2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xlf1/v/t34.0-12/12242102_10153806875886522_506967510_n.jpg?oh=fd0e83158fb5483c154d77121674fc75&oe=564F68CF]

**Does there exists a more user friendly (and presumably less cluttered) way to display this information?**

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: are students looking for a specific room?  If they don't care which room, then this view can be greatly simplified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find below some suggestions you may try :

- Use horizontal axis for time, much easier to read.
- Use grey font for hours. They are the less important information on the screen.
- Use less saturated colors for rooms. Saturated colors create more clutter.
- Do not repeat the hours in the room bars. They are not necessary.
- Display continuous bars. If two sessions in the same room are one after the other, do not show them as two bars, but as one. This information is unnecessary.
- Repeat hours for each day, this will minimize eye movements from users.
- Remove grey background from day labels.
- Add a grey line grid, this will help users more easily to identify empty rooms.
- Make day label font bold and large, the most mistakes people make with bookings is the day

The result may look something like this:

[image]

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar I'd also add the numbers (labels) of rooms on the left side. Color coding as the single mean doesn't work perfect: both for color-blinded, or new users. Also there is no sense to display non-actual info: on Friday, what's the reason to show the previous days?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of viewing the week in the columns, you could show the conference rooms in the columns. Then you can move the day of the week as a dropdown. I would think that most people are trying to schedule a meeting for a particular day and they can select the day, then see which times have room openings. That would de-clutter your chart.

Comment: edit:



my room booker app pretty much had a day selector at the top, not a drop down but something similar. most important thing is to show what rooms at any time

Answer (score 1):

If it was a smaller page designed for the booking process rather than a big electronic board I'd recommend just displaying one day at a time, with a dropdown to swap between them. But since this is designed to give an overview, my recommendation would be something like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpYUCi.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

The colour gradients represent how many rooms are free: dark colours mean few rooms, lighter colours mean more rooms. Some sacrifices must be made to reduce the clutter and I think the least important fact is which room is available. A different colour scheme may work to, from red to green for instance (but it could be unclear to colourblind users - not that the current system is super friendly to them!).

I may have it wrong, but I gather that the students look at the board to check if a room is available at their chosen time, and then book it on their separate device. They can see if a room is free at a glance - they don't know which room but it's not relevant until they log on, at which point a more detailed list is displayed.